# Is the substitution of variables allowed in proofs?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

EDIT: I later realized no one saw that substituting $\sqrt{x} =  x$ is not valid because they are not equal, you would have to assume $x$ as a completely different variable (i.e. $a$) and not the same one because they have no relation to each other. However, the solution to my proof problem is given.

So for example I have to prove:

$2y \leq \frac{y^2}{x^2} + x^2$ (for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ and $x$ $\neq$ $0$),

and I do some rough work at start with this and end up with the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality:

$\sqrt{xy} \le \frac{x+y}{2}$ (using substitution of variables).

Now to prove it, I start with the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, then do the following steps:

$\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$

$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$

Now, substitute $\sqrt{x}$ with $x$ and so:

$xy \leq x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}$

Then throughout, I do one more substitution:

$\sqrt{x} = x$

to end up with the first (1) equation. Would this be allowed or is there another way of proving it? Such as squaring the right side of arithmetic-geometric mean inequality? I am not too sure. Thanks.

Comment: You should show your work to go from (1) to $\sqrt{xy} \le x+y/2$.

Comment: It will depend on your audience.  For professional mathematicians, such substitution requires no explanation.  For beginners, it probably requires even more explanation than you showed here.

Comment: Hi, okay but what certain explanation did I not show? I am just trying to manipulate the equation to end up with the arithmetic-geometric inequality. Thank you.

Comment: Just play it safe and substitute a third variable.  let $w = \sqrt x$ and $z = \sqrt y$ and get $wz = \frac {w^2 + z^2}2$.

Comment: But you *don't* get $xy \le x^2 + \frac {y^2}2$.  You get $xy \le \frac {x^2 + y^2}2$ and doing it one more time doesn't give you the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$2y\le \frac{y^2}{x^2}+x^2 \iff2yx^2\le y^2+x^4 \iff x^4-2yx^2+y^2\ge 0$$

Comment: Hi, okay so after solving the quadratic I would get $(x^2-y)^2$ more than and equal to $0$. Would this be the starting point of my proof?

Comment: @Strikers We obtain $(x^2-y)^2\ge 0$? Is that always true?

Comment: No, it has to be squared for it to be more than or equal to $x^2-y^2$. Also how do you end of up with that equation after solving the quadratic you have given? Thanks

Comment: @Strikers Sorry there was a typo, now it is fixed!

Comment: Yes that is true, so that would be the starting point of my proof? Also I wouldn't have to use any substitution, even if that was allowed? Thanks

Comment: Then the proof ie ended, indeed we have proved that the initial statement is equivalent to another statement which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 > 0$ we have

$2y \le \frac {y^2}{x^2} + x^2 \iff yx^2 \le \frac{x^2 + x^4}2$.

Now do the substition.  Substitute $y = \sqrt a$ and $x^2 = \sqrt b$.

*EXCEPT* we don't know that $y$ is positive.

Let $y = \pm \sqrt a$ and $x^2 = \sqrt b$ so $y^2 = a \ge 0$ and $b = x^4 > 0$

And we know $\sqrt ab \le \frac {a+b}2$ for $a,b \ge 0$ so

$\sqrt {y^2} \sqrt {x^4} \le \frac {y^2 + x^4}2$ so

$|y|x^2 \le \frac {y^2 + x^4}2$ so

$2|y| \le \frac {y^2}{x^2} + x^2$ and finally

$2y \le 2|y| \le \frac {y^2}{x^2} + x^2$.

(remember $k \le |k|$ becuase if $k < 0$ then $k < 0 < |k|$.  And if $k \ge 0$ then $k = |k|$.)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer as it is understandable. However, how did you remove the plus/minus sign when doing the substitution for $y$? Thanks.

Comment: No, I did not remove it.  $(\pm y)^2 = y^2=a$.  And $\sqrt {a} =\sqrt{y^2} = |y|$.  And $y \le |y|$.  So, no, I did not remove it at all.

Comment: Hi. But did you not remove the possibility of $y$ being negative when you squared it?

Comment: No, negative numbers can be squared.  Squaring a number doesn't remove a possibility of a number being negative.  $y$ could very easily be negative.  But if $y$ is negative then $2y < 0$ and $0 < \frac {y^2}{x^2} + x^2$ so there is nothing to prove.  And I *did* state (*multiple* times) that $k \le |k|$ *always*.  So $2y \le 2|y|$ and $|y|$ is positive.

Comment: I proved $|y| \le \frac {y^2 + x^4}2$.  If $y \ge 0$ then $|y| = y$ and $y =|y| \le \frac {y^2 + x^4}2$.  If $y < 0$ then $|y| > 0$ and $y < 0 < |y| \le \frac {y^2 + x^4}2$.  Either way $y \le |y| \le \frac {y^2 + x^4}2$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks.